# Content below fixed-top-navbar (bootstrap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's a small piece of html code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="div1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">site</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Logoff</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </div>
  </div>
```

The fixed-top navbar stays on top of the hello,world, like shown on the picture.[image]

If i use just the navbar and navbar-default classes, the "hello, world" will appear normally. How can i make it appear normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.navbar-fixed-*` classes makes the navigation bar [fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), i.e. it moves along with your page while you're scrolling. This type of positioning takes it out of the document's flow, that's why the rest of the page behaves like it isn't there.

To fix your problem you should add some padding to the top of your page:

```
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

as advised in Bootstrap's [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top).